# I want to construct a function that satisfies the following restrictions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

A function u is $C^\infty (G)$ and bounded, but is not $C^1 (\bar G)$ where $G = \{x \in R^2: |x| < 1\}$
.......
I know this function should be have something to do with $e^x$ but I am not sure where I should start with
Hope for any help

Comment: $\sin(1/(1-|x|^2))$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Arthur no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function $$ u(x) := \sin \left( \frac1{1-|x|^2}\right)$$
satisfies your requirements. As $\sin$ is bounded, so is $u$. As $1/(1-|x|^2)$ is $C^\infty (G)$, so is $u$. But it fails to have a continuous extension to $\overline G$,  nevermind $C^1(\overline G)$.  (To see this, note that for any $\epsilon>0$, the image of $\{ 1-\epsilon < |x| < 1 \}$ under the radial function $u$ is $[-1,1]$).

Maybe you want a function that is $C^0(\overline G) \setminus C^1 (\overline G)$. Not a problem - consider then 
$$ v(x) := (1 - |x|^2)\sin \left( \frac1{1-|x|^2}\right).$$

Comment: (was hesitant to post as an answer because this has nothing to do with $e^x$, unless you count $\sin x = \Im \exp(i x)$ )

Comment: Perhaps a simpler answer would be $(1-|x|^2)^{1/2}$